# folding sub-elements in css file

Tags: css, optimization

I have following css snipet:

```css
 #div1 table, #div2 table, #div3 table  {
    color: white;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

may i fold it into something like below?

```css
 #(div1|div2|div3) table    {
    color: white;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

Comment: @Paulie_D it is not duplicate and not related to linked question. please remove that link as it is not answering my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it, if someone interested, below the answer:

```
[id$='-tabl'] table {
    color: white;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

in my case all DIV selectors have IDs ending on '-table', you can use regex "*^$" to match ID names.
But if you have different names, i didn't find a way for OR operator inside brackets like [id='name1||name2'], so not sure its even possible.